# How do I draw curved lines on an HTML page using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, graphics

Is it possible to draw curved lines in an HTML page (normally across cells in a table) using JavaScript (for web graph control)?

Comment: Too bad IE doesn't natively support SVG/CANVAS... these would be your best choice.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Raphael.js](http://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/) is a javascript library that lets you draw vector graphics on any webpage, any browser.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this using canvas element.

But isn't supported in some browsers.

[Drawing graphics with canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Drawing_Graphics_with_Canvas)

[Drawing shapes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Drawing_shapes)

Take a look at [this](http://www.walterzorn.com/jsgraphics/jsgraphics_e.htm) also

***Edit:***

The link provided by *@Joeri Sebrechts*

http://excanvas.sourceforge.net/

Comment: `canvas` tag is a part of a HTML5. I wouldn't recommend using it since IE doesn't support it (and IE is still browser user by most people worldwide) and other browsers that support it (Safari, Firefox and Opera) also have some issues with that:http://media.liquidx.net/js/plotkit-doc/SVGCanvasCompat.html

Comment: In IE I've had success using canvas by implementing it with ExplorerCanvas. It doesn't do high-performance stuff, but it is adequate for many purposes. http://excanvas.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I have added your comment as an edit to my answer. Thanks @Joeri Sebrechts

Comment: i just came to see the below site

its claiminng that IE supports canvas. below the links for demos using canvas.. i am using IE 7.. it just works 

http://media.liquidx.net/js/plotkit-tests/sweet.html
http://www.liquidx.net/plotkit/

am totally confused.. did they really use HTML 5 canvas element...??